# jQuery AJAX - How to show every couple seconds other results same table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

currently i have static show, wwhich show 3 last items from table :

DB Table :

```
  id        |        question       |      answer  
 -------------------------------------------------
 1          |           Q?          |     A?
 2          |           Q?          |     A?
 3          |           Q?          |     A?
 4          |           Q?          |     A?
 5          |           Q?          |     A?
 6          |           Q?          |     A?
```

So far i show with PHP foreach , last 3 items.

I want that it  will dynamicly will show every time each 3 items with nice animate and will loop forever.

How can i do it with ajax or what ? thanks in advance.

**EDIT(Deleted old codes).**

---

**Bahaaldine Azarmi,Here what i did:**

**1.** I created new php file called indexaskrefresh.php, inside that php i inserted the following php code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM que limit " .$offset. "," .$pageSize ;
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

$result = mysql_query($query, $func->connection);

if(!$result) //ERROR IN YOUR SQL QUERY
return false;

if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0) //NO ROWS IN TABLE pages
return false;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) // CHANGE THE RESULT TO 2 DIMMENSIONAL ARRAY
{
     $returned_array[] = $row;
}

return $returned_array;
```

**2.** Next in my index file i created new div called `ask` , and in the top of the page i created new javascript tags the following(Index.php):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 // global vars
var offset = 0;
var pageSize = 3;


function callMyPhpScript() {
    var parameters = new Object();
    parameters.offset = offset;
    parameters.pageSize = pageSize;
    $.ajax("modules/indexaskrefresh.php", parameters)
        .done(onDone)
        .fail(onFail);
}


function onDone(data) {
    // if no data was returned then you should reset the offset
    if ( data.length == 0 ) {
        offset = 0;
    } else {
        $('#ask').empty.append(data).show('slow');
        // I assume here that data is well formed 
        // html code returned by you php script
        offset += 3;
    }
}


 $(function() {
// should be move in configuration ...
var N = 5000 // Call will be made every 5 seconds. 
setInterval(callMyPhpScript,N);
  });


</script>
```

The div that should contain the response (Inside the Index.php):

```
   <div id="ask" style="float:right;">
         <h2 style="margin-right:15px;"> כדאי לדעת :</h2>
            <?php
                 $i = 0;
                  $len = count($que);
                    foreach($que as $key=>$value)
                    {   
                      echo '<span style="color:blue;font-weight:bold;padding:5px;">'.$value['que'].'</span><br><span style="color:green;font-weight:bold;padding:5px;">'.$value['ans'].'</span>';

                     if ($i == $len - 1) {

                        }else{
                        echo '<hr style="margin-right:25px;">';
                        }

                       $i++;
                    }
            ?>
          </div>
```

Nothing happens ,like the script not working not post nothing or somthing i dont know..

Answer (score 1):

So I assume you want that you want to call your PHP function every N seconds and refresh the 3 last items.

Here is one way to do that :

Create a javascript function which makes the call and send the offset and a page size.
The offset will be the starting id and the page size the limit in you SQL query :

```
// global vars
var offset = 0;
var pageSize = 3;


function callMyPhpScript() {
    var parameters = new Object();
    parameters.offset = offset;
    parameters.pageSize = pageSize;
    $.ajax("http://myhost:myport/pathToMyPhpFunction", parameters)
        .done(onDone)
        .fail(onFail);
}
```

In your php script, you should get the parse the parameters and use it in you SQL query like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM que limit " .$offset. "," .$pageSize ;
// That will return records from offset+1 to pageSize
```

Implement the onDone function to append the result in your HTML code

```
function onDone(data) {
    // if no data was returned then you should reset the offset
    if ( data.length == 0 ) {
        offset = 0;
    } else {
        $('#myContainer').empty.append(data).show('slow');
        // I assume here that data is well formed 
        // html code returned by you php script
        offset += 3;
    }
}
```

Then somewhere in you html code, when the page is loaded, call the setTimeout function
to make the call every N seconds :

```
$(function() {
    // should be move in configuration ...
    var N = 5000 // Call will be made every 5 seconds. 
    setInterval(callMyPhpScript,N);
});
```

If you want fancy effects, I recommand to use [Animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css//)

Comment: Sry for delay,i just will correct u , i want its will show each time other 3 items, Example : now its show id's : 1,2,3 then couple seconds will show 4,5,6 , and thanks for ur help

Comment: I've just edited the code, I now pass to the php script an offset and a page size parameter to fetch the data, and reset the offset when the php script doesn't return anything. In this last situation, that means that there is no more data to fetch.

You can also use the fail handler of the ajax call, to reset the offset, if any out of bound kind of exception occurs

Comment: You mean somthing like that in the first script : $.ajax("modules/indexaskrefresh.php", parameters) , and inside that php file should i put the query function? also i tryed ur method but nothing heppen, no error's no nothing

Comment: Yes that what I was meaning. What do you mean by nothing happens? You should have a response from your php script at least an error ... What is the structure of the php script response?

Comment: Nothing response, i will edit the steps i did,thanks u allot again.